# I get an error whenever I try to configure my Python Interpreter on PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, interpreter

Whenever I try to configure my Python Interpreter on PyCharm I get an error

> Standard Python 'venv' module not found.

What does it mean and how do I solve it?

Comment: what version of PyCharm are you using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61610042/standard-python-venv-module-not-found

Answer (score 0):

Ideally venv or virtual environment comes as a folder along with the installation in the IDE containing python.exe, you can try either specifying the path of python.exe inside venv explicitly in the Project Interpreter or reinstalling the IDE in the system.