# Standard Python 'venv' module not found

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create two virtual environments through Pycharm IDE.

- one for Python 2.7
- one for Python 3.8

However, I was able to create venv for 2.7 but could not succeed with 3.8; and end-up with "Error: Standard Python 'venv' module not found". as per [this reference]https://docs.python.org/3.7/installing/index.html) venv is already part of python3.8.

[image: Setup]
[image: Error]

So, It would great if someone help me with my following questions.

- Is it possible to setup two venv's with two different version of
  python?
- How do i know if my python3.8 has venv module?
- How can i install venv to python3.8 to be able to configure virtual environment in Pycharm?

Comment: From the looks of it you're using windows, so what does `python -m venv C:\path\to\venv\ ` give you?

Comment: Yes, indeed I am using windows. and when I try to create virtual environment from command prompt, I am getting "no module named venv" error

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this problem after installing the python 3.8 with executable installer. previously I got "Standard Python 'venv' module not found" problem because I have installed python 3.8 as embeddable zip file.

Answer (score 2):

download the executable installer not the embeddable zip file
[image: executable in green]